# How can I shrink the header on scroll down in android

Tags: android, scrollview

Here is the link http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/ where header will shrink while scroll down. **how can i get the same effect in android.**

Here is the sample

i have implemented this thing in OnScrollViewListener and in onScrollChanged i have write this code to achieve my objective but didn't get success.

- block_height is a fix heigt where i want to stop shrinking ....like 150
- currentHeight is a intial height of header which is double of  block_height .. like 300

please see the sample code

```
if (headerView.getLayoutParams().height <= (block_height * 2) 
&&  headerView.getLayoutParams().height >= block_height){

    currentHeight -= 1;
    headerView.getLayoutParams().height = currentHeight;
    headerView.invalidate();
 }
```

Comment: u need to use relative layout for the header and your main content.You will need two header one behind the other.One should be visible at one time and the the other should be hidden.Now try to detect the scroll.If your view at the top show the Big Header,as soon as it starts scrolling hide that and show small header.`RelativeLayout` lets you place and item over another.

Answer (score 2):

have look at this ActionBar Library may be fulfill your requirement

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code as:

```
if (headerView.getHeight() <= (block_height * 2) 
    &&  headerView.getHeight() >= block_height)
{
  currentHeight -= 1;
  headerView.layout(headerView.getLeft(), headerView.getTop(), 
                    headerView.getRight(), headerView.getTop()+currentHeight);
  headerView.forceLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by detecting scrollView's onScroll Event. Like this:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

        //Change your header size here

    }
});
```

You have to set some view that you want to be header above ScrollView and rest of the layout inside ScrollView. Then in onCreate() method of your Activity make use of the code I pasted for you